# organizing absolutely positioned table

Tags: html, css

hello i was trying to put one table row over another i made a Section as a wrapper and 2 figures with divs inside the section i made it relative and the figures were absolute  what troubles me is that when it set to absolute the table row becomes a column and i have no idea how to keep it as a row and just put the bottom row over the top one

this is what i got to i tried alot of different useless tricks and im just stumped :O

```css
section {
    display: table;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
figure {
    display: inline-block;
    display: table-row;
    max-width: 25%;
}
div.top {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
div.bottom {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
        <section style="position: relative;">
            <figure style="position: absolute;">
                <div class="top">H</div>
                <div class="top">G</div>
            </figure>
            <figure style="position: absolute;">
                <div class="bottom">A</div>
                <div class="bottom">B</div>
            </figure>
        </section>
```

Comment: May I ask why you are setting positions in such a way? What are you trying to accomplish by setting them to absolute?

Comment: every website i crossed upon about overlapping divs all the talk was about setting one div as relative and the other as absolute including adding z-index so i just rolled with it because i coudlnt find anything else

Answer (score 0):

It becomes a columns because it wraps.
When you give it absolute position it's "max-width" style is relative to "section".

I don't know what you want to achieve but look here.

When figure have 100% it stays horizontal:
https://jsfiddle.net/v0zq0en8/

```
width: 100%;
```

Another solution is to add "nowrap" to figure:
https://jsfiddle.net/0twvzbaq/

```
max-width: 25%;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: oh yes sorry i didnt write that i wanted to make a grid of 4 divs per row thats why it was 25%

Comment: if so then why width is on figure, but not on divs :) ?

Comment: oh my god :O i cant believe i made such a stupid mistake thanks alot i feel so stupid now haha XD

Answer (score 0):

In removing the position sets, both Divs line up as expected. Is [this jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jcjcy1b1/) not what you are looking for them to do?

```
<section>
  <figure>
    <div class="top">H</div>
    <div class="top">G</div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <div class="bottom">A</div>
    <div class="bottom">B</div>
  </figure>
</section>
```